How to export Custom Properties to be read in Unreal Engine
The Epic documentation describes a way to export custom attributes to be read as (anim) curves in Unreal. I'm attempting to do this with Blender. I've created a custom property (float) as part of my root deform bone and exported the rig and animation as GLB with "include custom property" checked ON.
The skeletal mesh and anim sequence import just fine in Unreal, however it doesn't appear to have picked up the custom property. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?


What import settings are you using when you import the GLB to Unreal?

Skeletal Mesh

Auto Detect Mesh: ON
Import Lods: ON
Keep Sections Separate: OFF
Vertex Color Import Option: Replace
Import Only Animations: OFF
Import Meshes in Bone Hierarchy: OFF
Use TOAs Ref Pose: OFF
Import Skeletal Meshes: ON
Import Content Type: Geometry and Skin Weights
Combine Skeletal Meshes: ON
Import Morph Targets: OFF
Import Vertex Attributes: OFF
Update Skeleton Reference Pose: OFF
Create Physics Asset: OFF


Try turning "Import Meshes in Bone Hierarchy" on, I think that could possibly fix your problem by helping Unreal recognize your custom property.

Hm, doesn't appear to have made any noticeable difference

I stumbled upon this question while I was trying to resolve this problem myself.
I haven't figured out yet why this is happening, but you can use Attributes now, at least as of Unreal 5.4.
First you have to define either the attribute/property names or bone names to get attributes from in Project Settings > Engine > Animation in the Animation Attributes category.

Then when you reimport your animation, the new Attributes should show up in the timeline. Here I have a Float custom property called "equip" on the "grip_gunblade" bone that I've defined in Blender.

You can access that attribute as you would a classic animation curve, you just need to specify the bone it's on.


Hopefully it helps!
